# fgets() weird behavior with realloc()

Tags: c, string, dynamic-memory-allocation, fgets, realloc

```
int main(void)
{
    int howMany,i,j;
    char* temp = NULL;
    char** friends = NULL;
    printf("Please enter the number of the friends you have\n");
    scanf(" %d",&howMany);
    howMany++;
    friends = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*)*howMany);
    for (i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
    {
        temp = (char*) malloc(20*sizeof(char));
        fgets(temp,20,stdin);
        temp[strspn(temp, "\n")] = '\0';
        *(friends + i) = (char*)realloc(temp,sizeof(char) * (strlen(temp)+1));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < strlen(*(friends+i)); j++)
        {
            printf("%c",friends[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
    {
        free(*(friends + i));
    }

    free(friends);
    getchar();  
    return 0;
}
```

The purpose of my code is to get the amount of friends i have, their names and finally printing it to the screen, any ideas why my code isn't working?

Input: 
2 
daniel
david

Output:

(\n)

Expected output:
daniel
david

Comment: How is it *not working*?

Comment: I am confused aswell @YuHao

Comment: No， describe how it's not working, e.g, your input, the expected output, the current output, etc.

Comment: Actual output is?   This is getting to be like pulling teeth...

Comment: Why do you write `*(friends+i)` instead of the more intuitive `friends[i]`?  They're entirely equivalent.

Comment: 'howMany++;' ??  Does that not force you to enter three friends, 0,1,2?

Comment: You increment `howMany`, hence the program expects three names when you specify `2`. (The first name will be blank, though, because it consists of the rest of the line after scanning the number of names. Fix the input instead of making the first name blank. It is usually a bad idea to mix token-based input with `scanf` and line-based input with `fgets`.)

Comment: ..something that would have been obvious if you had run your program under your debugger..

Comment: howMany increment in necessary foe getting the input from the user twice

Comment: "howMany increment in necessary" No, it isn't if you design your input properly: When you scan the number of names, read a line first, then scan that line for a number with `sscanf`. Better don't mix `fgets` and `scanf`.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is here:

```
temp[strspn(temp, "\n")] = '\0';
```

You used the wrong function.  You want `strcspn`, not `strspn`.  Change it to:

```
temp[strcspn(temp, "\n")] = '\0';
```

Also, as others pointed out, you should not change the value of `howMany`, since you need its original value in your loops.

Comment: @Martin R "Or `strchr(temp, '\n')`" lacks context.  Used incorrectly like `*strchr(temp, '\n')  = '\0';` is the beginning of a hacker's exploit.  To use properly:  `{ char *p = strchr(temp, '\n'); if (p) *p = '\0';}`